# How to measure critical current of a superconducting wire, if my current source can only supply a small current?

Tags: magnetic-fields, measurements, superconductivity, experimental-technique, cryogenics

I need to determine the critical current of an aluminum wire at 0.1Kelvin. I have access to dilution fridges, but I cannot modify the wiring in the system from room temperature to the sample space. Because of that restriction, I cannot supply the full (by calculation) current needed to make the aluminum wire go normal.

Can I make my aluminum wire-under-test as the 1-turn secondary of an aircore transformer, where the primary is 30 turns of superconducting wire? I would install the transformer in the sample space. I would drive the primary coil with the maximum allowable (by the fridge wiring) current. If there is a 30X amplification for the current in the secondary loop, I may be able to exceed the critical current of the aluminum wire-under-test.

Questions:

1. For a DC current, would there be amplification based on the turns ratio?

   - A1) [This link](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=2372) says the answer is "yes".
2. How can I measure the effective turns ratio (at 0.1Kelvin)?
3. How would I detect that the secondary coil has gone normal?